# Keep order position through further table

Tags: sql-server

Have 3 tables as follows:

```
T_Artikel_T_Variation
------------------------------------
ID
FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID
FK_Artikel_ID
Position

T_Variation_VariationAttribute
------------------------------------
ID
FK_Variation_ID

T_Variation
------------------------------------
ID
Name
```

Target is to take records from `T_Variation` table based on `FK_Artikel_ID` but its strongly important to take them by Position from `T_Artikel_T_Variation`.

I got query but the problem is when I get records firstly from `T_Artikel_T_Variation` by Position and then those records when I use to take `FK_Variation_ID` from `T_Variation_VariationAttribute` (in this table `FK_Variation_ID` **can be in other position**) therefore at the end taking from `T_Variation` I can get by other position from `T_Variation` than it was in `T_Artikel_T_Variation`.

Is there any way to keep the position order?

Current query:

```
;WITH var_varattr (FK_Variation_ID) As (
    SELECT FK_Variation_ID 
    FROM T_Variation_VariationAttribute 
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID 
        FROM T_Artikel_T_Variation 
        WHERE FK_Artikel_ID = 46 
        ORDER BY Position ASC
        )
)
SELECT  Id, 
        Name 
FROM T_Variation 
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT FK_Variation_ID 
    FROM var_varattr
    )
```

Comment: In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Specifically, you don't really control what order it accesses each base table in, what order it applies predicates, etc. And the only `ORDER BY` clause that affects the order of results is one on the outermost query. Anywhere else, it's solely used to make other features (such as `TOP`) well-*defined*.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I really understood what you need, but - this for sure! - the `ORDER BY` **within** the `IN-clause` won't help you.

An `ORDER BY` should be applied to the outer-most `SELECT` (But you might think about `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`...)

Give this a try:

```
;WITH var_varattr (FK_Variation_ID) As 
(
    SELECT FK_Variation_ID 
    FROM T_Variation_VariationAttribute 
    WHERE ID IN
        (
        SELECT FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID 
        FROM T_Artikel_T_Variation 
        WHERE FK_Artikel_ID = 46 
        )
)
select v.Id, v.Name 
FROM T_Variation AS v
INNER JOIN T_Variation_VariationAttribute AS va ON v.ID=va.FK_VariationID
INNER JOIN T_Artikel_T_Variation AS a ON va.ID=a.FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID
WHERE v.ID IN 
    (
        SELECT FK_Variation_ID from var_varattr
    )
ORDER BY a.Position ASC
```

Comment: I get duplicated records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT  t.Id, 
        t.Name 
FROM T_Variation t
INNER JOIN T_Variation_VariationAttribute v
    ON t.ID = v.FK_Variation_ID 
INNER JOIN T_Artikel_T_Variation a
    ON v.ID = a.FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID 
        AND a.FK_Artikel_ID = 46 
ORDER BY a.Position ASC
```

You will get duplicates because there can be more then 1 `Position` for same row from `T_Variation`. So here is a question, how must be this rows be ordered for more then one `Position`?